# python pandas create hyperlink to image file while writing csv

Tags: python, pandas, hyperlink

This is data frame i am working with:
{'Image File': {0: 'C:\Users\Param1.png',
  1: 'C:\Users\Param2.png',
  2: 'C:\Users\Param3.png'},
 'Param': {0: 'Param1', 1: 'Param2', 2: 'Param3'}}
I would like to create hyper link in csv file to Image File with following statement:

```
Data['HYPERLINK'] = "<a href=\"Test\">"+Data['Image File']+"</a>"
```

My problem that as hyperlink i see the path i am supplying in "Image File" column, but i am interested in Param column value be as caption for hyperlink.
any thoughts?
Thank you

Comment: Disagree, different issue

Comment: Table with additional column HYPERLINK with hyperlinks to image files while caption on hyperlinks are values from Param column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the link text shown being your `Param` field, you need to add it to the link. In your example syntax this would be:

```
Data['HYPERLINK'] = "<a href=\"" + Data['Image File'] + "\">"+Data['Param']+"</a>"
```

The html link syntax is

```
<a href="url">link text</a>
```

see here for details: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp